# Automatically displaying shipping cost in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I have set my shipping rules with Owebia-Shipping 2. I set them so that for a cart there is only one possible shipping cost not depending on the shipping destination. For now, the user has to enter its shipping destination to see the shipping cost as it is on the image below :

[image]

I would like Magento to automatically display the shipping cost without needing for the user to enter its address and choose a method, since there will only one displaying and it won't depend on the shipping destination.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing this module: https://github.com/philwinkle/Mage_Autoquote